# Extract list from a Python script in web scraped html page

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm new to web scraping and ran into a small road block with the following code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "www.website.com"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
price_scripts = soup.find_all('script')[23]
print(price_scripts)
```

The scripts that are pulled all appear to be Python scripts. Here's what's printed from the above code:

```
<script>
        p.a = [0,"6.93","9.34","3.42","7.88"];
        p.output();
</script>
```

What I'm trying to do is pull the list from this script, but when I attempt it just returns "None".

Comment: What are you running that returns "None"? The `print(price_scripts)` is doing so or? There isn't enough information here. What are the contents of `soup.find_all('script')[23]`? Can you provide some form of output for what is being stored in `price_scripts`? Also, in HTML, these are not Python but are Javascript. If the `<script>` output is what your output is from print, what are you doing that is returning "None" when attempting to grab the list?

Comment: Is www.website.com the actual website you are trying to scrape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to extract the data this way:

```
target = price_scripts.text
```

which outputs:

```
p.a = [0,"6.93","9.34","3.42","7.88"];
    p.output();
```

At this point you need to resort to string manipulation, by stripping out everything between the brackets, like so:

```
print(target.text.split('[')[1].split(']')[0])
```

Note that each use of the `split()` method creates a list, so you have to choose the correct element from the list.
output:

> 0,"6.93","9.34","3.42","7.88"

Comment: that did it! thank you! Don't know why I didn't think about using a split method. cheers!